# Can not see useminPrepare results

Tags: build, gruntjs, grunt-usemin

Yeoman build task breaks my app out of the box and I am trying to see where is the problem.

So I commented out the other tasks and only left:

```
grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'useminPrepare',
]);
```

And useminPrepre task is defined like this:

```
useminPrepare: {
            html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
            options: {
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                flow: {
                    steps: {'js': ['concat']},
                    post: {}
                }
            }
        },
```

The output (see below) seem Ok but the `dist` folder is empty, once the build is done. How can I make useminPrepare to actually write the files?

```
Running "useminPrepare:html" (useminPrepare) task
Going through C:/development/projects/yadazing/bb_ui/app/index.html to update the config
Looking for build script HTML comment blocks

Configuration is now:

  concat:
  { generated:
   { files:
      [ { dest: '<APP_PATH> \\dist\\scripts\\scripts.js',
          src:
           [ '{.tmp,app}\\bower_components\\jquery\\jquery.js',
             <APP_COMPONENTS>\\angular.js'
             .
             .
             ] },

        { dest: ''<APP_PATH>\\dist\\scripts\\modules.js',
          src:
           [ '<APP_MUDULES>\\app\\scripts\\app.js',
             '<APP_MUDULES>\\app\\scripts\\settings.js',
              .
              .
              ]}]}}

Done, without errors.


Execution Time (2014-02-19 22:46:34 UTC)
loading tasks        5ms  
clean:dist           5ms  
useminPrepare:html  26ms
Total 37ms
```

Answer (score 0):

All that useminprepare does is modify the configuration of *other* grunt tasks. To see the result of the generated task configuration, you'll need to run those tasks afterwards.

That collection of tasks, and the order that they execute in, is called the [*flow*](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin#transformation-flow). By default the flow is `concat -> uglifyjs`, but you can write your own flows.

Using the default flow you would need to execute:

```
grunt.registerTask( 'lala', ['useminprepare', 'concat', 'uglify'] );
```

to see the results.

Comment: According to the docs: https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin. dist is the "Base directory where the transformed files should be output."

Comment: Yes, for the `usemin` task. This is `useminprepare`. They're two different tasks.

Comment: How can I see the generated task configuration? I tried runnin grunt with -verbose but it didn't help.